# using javascript in kompozer for textbox validation

Tags: javascript, validation, textbox

I am using javascript in Kompozer to validate a textbox. I have looked up videos and researched how to do this, but it still doesn't seem to be working for me. This is what I have for the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function nameValidate(){
valid = true;
if(document.getElementById('Username').value==""){
alert("Please enter your username");
valid = false;
}
return valid;
}
</script>
```

And this is the form for the Username textbox:

```
<input size="25" name="Username" action="Account Home.html"
id="Username" onsubmit="return nameValidate();">
```

I am missing something though because nothing happens when I just click on the Login button. I am trying to figure this simple part first before I can actually have an error if it doesn't contain "@umary.edu" email address. What am I doing wrong or missing?/Is there more resources that could help me to solve this problem.

Comment: The input element is not the form. Onsubmit is not a valid attribute for input.

Comment: Where would I put the action, id, and onsubmit?